# Zoom on chart not working in react-plotly.js

Tags: reactjs, plotly

I have created a bar chart with rangeslider using react-plotly.js. I want to enable drag and zoom feature on chart area as provided by the library. But that feature is not working for me. The fixedRange attribute of layout is not true. The cursor changes to the double arrow cursor but when I perform drag action, nothing happens. The area selected is not highlighted and not even zoomed in. But when I double click, the area get zoomed out. 
My layout settings looks like:

```
const layout = {
        title: this.state.chartTitle,
        autosize: true,
        dragmode: false,
        // showlegend: true,
        margin: {
          r: 0,
          t: 50,
          b: 100,
          pad: 0,
          autoexpand: true
        },
        scrollZoom: true,
        hoverlabel: {
          bgcolor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
          bordercolor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)'
        },
        width: this.state.layoutWidth,
        height: '750',
        yaxis: {
          title: this.state.yaxisTitle,
          type: 'linear',
          showgrid: true
        },
        xaxis: {
          title: this.props.intl.formatMessage(messages.xAxisTitle),
          type: this.state.xaxisType,
          autorange: false,
          showgrid: false,
          range: this.state.axisRange,
          rangeslider: {
            visible: true,
            range: this.state.sliderRange
          }
        }
```

I even tried scrollZoom attribute but that doesn't work either. The version of plotly.js and react-plotly.js that I am using is :

```
"plotly.js": "^1.41.3",
"react-plotly.js": "^2.2.0",
 "react-plotlyjs": "^0.4.4",
```

Am I suppose to also add some css settings to it ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting 
`scrollZoom: true` to layout, please try to put it into the config tree, like:

```
const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(Plot, {
    data: [...],
    layout: {...}, 
    config: {
      scrollZoom: true,
    }
  }),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Yup this solution worked. Also, when i changed dragmode to true the zoom started working. Not sure why though :)